# Can you authenticate into SSAS with AD LDS (ADAM) accounts?

Tags: active-directory, sql-server-2008, sql-server, ad-lds

I'm very new to AD LDS and experienced but not qualified with SSAS, so my apologies for my ignorances with these.

We have a couple implementations where we expose SSAS via an HTTPS proxy (msmdpump.dll) and currently we have a temporary domain setup handling this (where our end-users have a second account+creds to manage because of this = non-ideal). I want to move us towards a more permanent solution which I'm thinking of moving all authentication to AD LDS for our web apps, SSAS, and others. However, SSAS is where I'm concerned about this.

I know SSAS requires Windows Authentication and to play nicely, and that this ultimately means Active Directory will be involved.

**Is there a way to get this done with AD LDS instead of having to use a full AD DS implementation? If so, how?**

(Note: My question over at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455775/can-you-authenticate-into-ssas-with-ad-lds-adam-accounts) had a suggestion that I post this question here on ServerFault instead. My apologies if I'm not asking in the right forum.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up just going with full-blown AD-DS.